# C#: How to extend PropertyInfo?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I have a solution where i get to map out all properties and sub-properties of an object into a Dictionary.
Lets say I have something like these objects:

```
class MyClassA{
    string info;
}
class MyClassB{
    string info;
}
class MyClassC{
    MyClassA a;
    MyClassB b;
    string something;
}
class MyClassD{
    MyClassC c;
}
```

I created an utility to map out all the propreties so i can get something like:

```
MyClassD dObject = Something();
Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propertyMap = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();

propertyMap = buildPropertyMap(dObject );
```

where the string is the path and the PropertyInfo the actual property. The strings on the Map on this example would look like this (pseudo-output):

```
propertyMap.Keys={
    c;
    c.a;
    c.b;
    c.a.info;
    c.b.info;
    c.something;
}
```

This is a great way to tell what goes where when reading for example data from an excel file and not from xml-like things, like so:

ExcelTableC:

```
 -----------------------
1|Ainfo|Binfo|Csomething|
-------------------------
2|value|value|valuevalue|
3|value|value|valuevalue|
 -----------------------
```

It wall works great.
Now thing is, this is all obviously inside a couple of loops and diferent functions (because of the Excel reading process) and i need later to get the key, this is, lets say I have this 'property' and I want the path (dont ask why):

```
// this method does not exist (pseudo-code)
PropertyInfo.GetPath; //it would return 'c.b.info' for ex. or 'c.a.info'
```

So i wanted to implement a class that extended PropertyInfo to add my methods.

But doing something like:

```
public class PropertyField : PropertyInfo
{
    PropertyField parent;
    string path;
    // etc...
}
```

returns error because PropertyInfo is an abstract class and I would need to implement all inhereted members.

I can add 'abstract' to 'PropertyField' like this:

```
public abstract class PropertyField : PropertyInfo {}
```

But then when i try to cast it like this :

```
private void findProperties(Type objType)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();

    for (int i=0; i< properties.Length; i++)
    {
        //PropertyInfo propertyInfo = properties[i];
        PropertyField property = (PropertyField) properties[i];
        //do something with it
    }
}
```

will return the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'App.models.PropertyField'.
```

So the question is, how do I add these methods? If I cant inherit what can i do?

Comment: [Prefer composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) :)

Comment: There's something I'm not understanding about composition, would i have to reinvent the wheel and re-implement all the methods of the derived class, this case all 'PropertyInfo's methods?

Comment: Why do you need to implement all of them? In most of the cases, you don't need all the methods/properties. Do you? Expose only whatever you need. [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
public class PropertyField
{
    PropertyField parent;
    string path;
    PropertyInfo info;
    // etc...
}
```

I see no point in inheriting PropertyInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Use [exstension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to extend the `PropertyInfo` class instead of inhriting it.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetPath(this PropertyInfo pi)
    {
        // Your implementation to get the path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, better derive from `PropertyDescriptor` than from `PropertyInfo`. While the latter is used by the runtime environment and instantiated in `RuntimePropertyInfo` objects, the latter is used really to meet your purpose, to describe the property. Property descriptors have been used quite a lot in Windows.Forms, basically the whole WinForms designer is built on them and they are quite powerful.

And: you can easily inherit ``PropertyDescriptor`and you even do not have to recreate a whole lot of functionality since`PropertyDescriptor` has constructors that allow you to pass in a name and a set of attributes.